# extract images from pdf using pdfx python 2.6

Tags: python, xml, pdf

I want to compare two pdf files(text+images) in python. So I decided to convert pdf to xml and comapare the xml files .

To convert my pdf files to xml I used the following code found in : `https://gist.github.com/yoavram/4351598`

```
def pdfToxml(inFile,outFile):

    url = "http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk"
    fin = open(inFile , 'rb')
    files = {'file': fin}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers={'Content-Type':'application/pdf'})
    finally:
        fin.close()
    fout = open(outFile , 'w')
    fout.write(r.content)
    fout.close()
```

example : for the following pdf file:    `http://www.arvindguptatoys.com/arvindgupta/nimrethanda.pdf`

I get the following xml file:

```
<pdfx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/static/article-schema.xsd">
<meta>
  <job>15efe863ea5359795898d317017f1b6261730810dca11f0ef26606a0c2ea19b0</job>
  <base_name>4ffa</base_name>
  <doi confidence="possible" alt_doi="http://dx.doi.org/10.5962/bhl.title.27728">http://dx.doi.org/10.5962/bhl.title.25688</doi>
</meta>
<article>
     <front class="DoCO:FrontMatter">
     <title-group>
         <article-title class="DoCO:Title" id="1">WILD FLOWERS OF INDIA</article-title>
     </title-group>
     <contrib-group class="DoCO:ListOfAuthors">
         <contrib contrib-type="author">
             <name id="2">NIMRET HANDA</name>
         </contrib>
     </contrib-group>
     <region class="DoCO:FigureBox" id="Fx3">
          <image class="DoCO:Figure" src="4ffa.page_001.image_01.png"  thmb="4ffa.page_001.image_01-thumb.png"/>
     </region>
     <outsider class="DoCO:TextBox" type="header" id="4">INTRODUCTION</outsider>
     <region class="DoCO:TextChunk" id="8">
         Wild flowers are to be found in all kinds of unexpected places ...
     </region>
     <region class="DoCO:FigureBox" id="Fx6">
           <image class="DoCO:Figure" src="4ffa.page_003.image_02.png" thmb="4ffa.page_003.image_02-thumb.png"/>
     </region>  ...
```

My problem is that I want to access the images in my code and compare them (for every image tag I want to compare images) and I don't know how or even is it possible to access the extracted images ?

Thanks